# axios: how to merge transformRequest

Tags: javascript, axios

```js
axios.defaults.transformRequest = [
  (data, headers) => {
    console.log('default config')
    // ...some code
    return qs.stringify(data)
  }
]

function postData(value) {
  axios.post('/xxx', value, {
    transformRequest: [data => {
      console.log('postData config')
      const { aProp, ...rest } = data
      if (isX(aProp)) {
        return { ...rest, x: aProp }
      }
      return { ...rest, y: aProp }
    }]
  })
}
```

Expected output:

```
postData config
default config
```

But only output `postData config`.

The `transformRequest` seems like merged by index, not using `concat`. So how can I make both functions called?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that's not possible like the way you written, as Axios is just overriding the `transformRequest` property of global config by request specific config.

Please take a look at the code that is in `mergeConfig.js`

in below code snippets
`config2` is request specific config
`config1` is global config

```
  var valueFromConfig2Keys = ['url', 'method', 'data'];
  var mergeDeepPropertiesKeys = ['headers', 'auth', 'proxy', 'params'];
  var defaultToConfig2Keys = [
    'baseURL', 'transformRequest', 'transformResponse', 'paramsSerializer',
    'timeout', 'timeoutMessage', 'withCredentials', 'adapter', 'responseType', 'xsrfCookieName',
    'xsrfHeaderName', 'onUploadProgress', 'onDownloadProgress', 'decompress',
    'maxContentLength', 'maxBodyLength', 'maxRedirects', 'transport', 'httpAgent',
    'httpsAgent', 'cancelToken', 'socketPath', 'responseEncoding'
  ];
  var directMergeKeys = ['validateStatus'];
```

Only `mergeDeepPropertiesKeys` are deep merged like here

```
  function mergeDeepProperties(prop) {
    if (!utils.isUndefined(config2[prop])) {
      config[prop] = getMergedValue(config1[prop], config2[prop]);
    } else if (!utils.isUndefined(config1[prop])) {
      config[prop] = getMergedValue(undefined, config1[prop]);
    }
  }
  utils.forEach(mergeDeepPropertiesKeys, mergeDeepProperties);
```

`defaultToConfig2Keys` are just overriden by request specific config like below and `transformRequest` is one of those properties.

```
  utils.forEach(defaultToConfig2Keys, function defaultToConfig2(prop) {
    if (!utils.isUndefined(config2[prop])) {
      config[prop] = getMergedValue(undefined, config2[prop]);
    } else if (!utils.isUndefined(config1[prop])) {
      config[prop] = getMergedValue(undefined, config1[prop]);
    }
  });
```

**PS: I would suggest you to write your own wrapper around axios or you can prepare your data ahead before making the request.**